# Why JupyterLab not installed?

Tags: pipenv, jupyter-lab

I want to install Jupyter Lab from github, and do it, and all ok, 
but I am getting the following exception:

> "Exception: Jupyter command `jupyter-lab` not found."

What am I missing?

```
    $ pipenv install -e git+git://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab.git#egg=jupyterlab


    Installing collected packages: ipython-genutils, decorator, six, traitlets, Send2Trash, attrs, pyrsistent, jsonschema, jupyter-core, nbformat, ptyprocess, tornado, terminado, python-dateutil, pyzmq, jupyter-client, entrypoints, testpath, MarkupSafe, jinja2, webencodings, bleach, pygments, defusedxml, pandocfilters, mistune, nbconvert, parso, jedi, wcwidth, prompt-toolkit, pickleshare, pexpect, backcall, ipython, ipykernel, prometheus-client, notebook, json5, jupyterlab-server, jupyterlab
      Running setup.py develop for jupyterlab
    Successfully installed MarkupSafe-1.1.1 Send2Trash-1.5.0 attrs-19.1.0 backcall-0.1.0 bleach-3.1.0 decorator-4.4.0 defusedxml-0.6.0 entrypoints-0.3 ipykernel-5.1.1 ipython-7.7.0 ipython-genutils-0.2.0 jedi-0.14.1 jinja2-2.10.1 json5-0.8.5 jsonschema-3.0.2 jupyter-client-5.3.1 jupyter-core-4.5.0 jupyterlab jupyterlab-server-1.0.0 mistune-0.8.4 nbconvert-5.5.0 nbformat-4.4.0 notebook-6.0.0 pandocfilters-1.4.2 parso-0.5.1 pexpect-4.7.0 pickleshare-0.7.5 prometheus-client-0.7.1 prompt-toolkit-2.0.9 ptyprocess-0.6.0 pygments-2.4.2 pyrsistent-0.15.4 python-dateutil-2.8.0 pyzmq-18.0.2 six-1.12.0 terminado-0.8.2 testpath-0.4.2 tornado-6.0.3 traitlets-4.3.2 wcwidth-0.1.7 webencodings-0.5.1


    $ pipenv shell

    $ jupyter --version
    jupyter core     : 4.5.0
    jupyter-notebook : 6.0.0
    qtconsole        : not installed
    ipython          : 7.7.0
    ipykernel        : 5.1.1
    jupyter client   : 5.3.1
    jupyter lab      : not installed
    nbconvert        : 5.5.0
    ipywidgets       : not installed
    nbformat         : 4.4.0
    traitlets        : 4.3.2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try running `pip install jupyterlab` that fixed it for me

Here are the docs to get it running
https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started/installation.html

Comment: this didn't work for me. It just reported back that requirements had been met, and jupyterlab was NOT installed. after repeated tries.